# Can anyone help finding what's shady things are logged on my nginx webserver?

Tags: ssh, brute-force, vulnerability-scanners, logging, nginx

I have a hosted a simple react website(testing) with nginx webserver and cloudflare as ssl provider.My website is down from few days with cloudflare error 525 "SSL handshake failed".I was pretty sure my SSL keys are not expired,so i checked nginx logs.Can you please help identify the issue with these screenshots ?[image: Combined Screenshot]

Comment: What you see in the access log is unrelated to SSL handshake problems. Any information about this are more likely to find in the error log.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes i thought someone executed some nasty shell script that may caused the issue.Can you please check this screenshot it is from the nginx access logs https://imgur.com/a/VKUf6O1

Comment: This does not look like a security related issue. SSL errors in logs happen also from scanning sites like SSLLabs. If you can clearly associate (by time) the cloudflare error with specific log messages then you might ask such kind of question at serverfault.com. Don't forget to include your server configuration there too.

Comment: Thank @SteffenUllrich for clarifying my doubts. Sure,i'll investigate more and will ask my questions at serverfault.com